# Recover Pose OpenCV 3.0

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have calibrated my pinhole camera using opencv 3.0 and got 4 intrinsic parameters (f_x,f_y,u_0,v_0) plus some distortion coefficients. Using this calibration, I estimate the essential matrix from two images at different positions. Finally I want to recover (R|t) using the recover pose function from opencv 3.0. The interface of this function expects a single focal length, but I have two from the calibration procedure. How can a  get the focal length f=f_y/s_y = f_x/s_x (Definition according to OpenCV) from f_x an f_y so that I can properly use the recover pose function?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the horizontal focal length f_x. The ratio f_y/f_x is just the pixel aspect ratio, an estimate the squareness of the pixels.

Note that, unless you have some absolute scale reference in your image pair (e.g. an object of known size), you can recover pose only up to scale, that is, R and s*t for some unknown scale s.

Comment: f_x as returned by calibrateCamera is in pixel units.  The recoverPose() function requires focal length in units of mm. Therefor it is necessary to convert them. This can be done if you know the size of your CMOS sensor. Alternatively, use the focal length (in mm) published by the camera/lens manufacturer.

Comment: @Derec Simkowiak, a couple of errors there: (1) f_x's and f_y's units are pixel/length, where the length is measured in the units of the calibration object, e.g. width of the checkerboard squares in the usual OpenCV setup. (2) It is more correct to say that recoverPose() _returns_ the translation in the same units as the given focal length, be they pixels, mm, inches or kilometers. 

Absolute scale can be obtained, as you say, from knowledge of the sensor, but it can also be recovered from the calibration procedure if the geometry of the calibration rig is known.

Comment: Upon further reading recoverPose() does not expect focal length in mm, although, that is not clear from the documentation. In contrast, the documentation for calibrationMatrixValues() does say it expects mm.

@Francesco, re: your point (2), my understanding is that the returned translation is a unit vector indicating the direction of translation but not distance.  That's a little different from a t that is an absolute translation in some arbitrary units (such as checkerboard square units). I'd love to read any references on this subject, esp. how to convert t to absolute units.

Comment: Through experiments I have confirmed that recoverPose() always returns a unit vector for translation. So, it gives the direction, but not the distance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really derive the actual focal length just from f_x and f_y. For a pinhole camera the actual focal length is the distance from the pinhole to the imaging plane. Your camera probably has the focal length written somewhere in the specs.